# Why can't I keep component-related actions within the component in this Svelte app?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am working on a small Users app in Svelte for learning purposes (Im new to Svelte).

In App.Svelte, I loop through a set of users:

```
<script>
const apiURL = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import Search from './Search.svelte';
import User from './User.svelte';

let users = [];
let stringToMatch = "";

$:filteredUsers = users;

 onMount(() => {
    getUsers();
});

const getUsers = () => {
let getFrom = "&results=20&inc=name,location,email,cell,picture";
fetch(`${apiURL}?${getFrom}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => users = data.results);
};

let filterUsers = () => {
    if (stringToMatch) {
        filteredUsers = users.filter(user => {
            return user.name.first.toLowerCase().includes(stringToMatch.toLowerCase()) ||
                user.name.last.toLowerCase().includes(stringToMatch.toLowerCase()) ||
                user.location.city.toLowerCase().includes(stringToMatch.toLowerCase());
        });
    } else filteredUsers = users;
};

</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card bg-light mb-2 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="card-header px-2 py-0 d-flex">
            <h6 class="text-dark m-0 align-self-center">Members Area</h6>
        </div>
            <div class="card-body bg-white p-0">
            <Search {filterUsers} bind:stringToMatch={stringToMatch} />
            {#if filteredUsers.length > 0}
                <table class="table users-table m-0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-right">#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Lives in</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {#each filteredUsers as user,index (user)}
                            <User {user} {index} on:Delete = {deleteUser(user)} />
                        {/each}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            {:else}
                <p class="text-center text-muted my-3">No members found</p>
            {/if}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As can be seen in the loop above, I display every user from a `User.svelte` component. It seems logical that every user-related *action* (like deleting a user, for instance) show live in this component. So, it is here that I have:

```
const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
const Delete = () => dispatch("deleteUser", user);

const deleteUser = (user) => {
    let itemIdx = filteredUsers.findIndex(x => x == user);
    filteredUsers.splice(itemIdx, 1);
    filteredUsers = filteredUsers;
}
```

Yet, I get this `'deleteUser' is not defined` error, as can be seen in the **[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a0b0c71a600f4c40bb9b685439378d16?version=3.29.0)**.

#### Question(s)

- What am I doing wrong?
- How can I keep the `deleteUser` method within `User.svelte` and use it successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `deleteUser` in the `User` component, but you are trying to use it in `App` were it is indeed not defined. So the error is not that strange imo.

One of the problems you have is that your delete function is acting upon an array that is *not part of the component* (filteredUsers), so even if you would call `deleteUser` directly inside the component you would just get another *undefined* error.

What I see here is that you, logically, want to keep all the logic dealing with an individual user inside `User`, but by doing so you take in logic that deals with the users as whole (the array), which is inconsistent: the users as an array itself is part of `App`, why would you want to take logic related with the array out of where it belongs ?

In my opinion, **deleting a user** is not a function executed by an item on itself but is a function done by the holder of the array. So in your case you would be better of moving the `deleteUser` up to `App`.

If you do it this way, the User component will be responsible for

- display an *individual* user
- potentially edit an *individual* user

And the App will be responsible for

- display a *list* of users
- adding/removing users of said *list*

Comment: You *are* making sense. Yet, my questions is about being able to keep component-related actions within the component. How would you do _that_ for editing a user, if it suits you? Thanks!

Comment: You will add all code related to changing the user inside the component, after making changes you can then raise an event informing the parent that this unit has changed allowing it to update the list in turn. Alternatively you can start looking at stores.